# HTMLAudioElement Error, DOMException: The element has no supported sources

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry if the formatting is pretty bad, I am getting the error shown above. I have tried a bunch of fixes but nothing seems to work. It should only update the audio if changeAudio changes values. The src for the window object url seems to work, and I got the HTMlAudioElement working with a simpler solution that just played audio if a button was pressed.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'
import {url} from '../App'
const pause = 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/61/61180.svg'
const play = 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/109/109197.svg'
var audio_url = ''
var audio;

const AudioPlayer = ({pk, changeAudio=true, timeChange}) => {
    var [playing, setPlay] = useState(true)
    var [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/61/61180.svg')
useEffect(async () => {
    const res =  await Axios.get(url + 'audioupload/' + pk, {
        responseType: 'blob'
    })
    const mp3 = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'audio/mp3' })
    const audio_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(mp3)
    audio = new Audio(audio_url)
    audio.load()

}, [changeAudio])
const changeTime = (timeChange) => {
    audio.currentTime = audio.currentTime + timeChange
}

const pausePlay = async () => {
    if(playing){
        setImgSrc(pause)
        setPlay(false)
        audio.pause()
    }else{
        setImgSrc(play)
        setPlay(true)
        try{
            await audio.play()
        }catch(e){
            console.log('audio error:', e)
        }
    }
}
if (audio_url !== ''){
    if(changeTime !== undefined){
        changeTime(timeChange)
    }
}

return (
    <div>
        <img src={imgSrc} onClick={pausePlay}/>
    </div>
);
}




export default AudioPlayer;
```